# Is the following omission of "it was" permissible in colloquial English?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

> Bringing up the question wasn't as hard as he'd thought. (It was)
>   Definitely easier than the letter he'd have to write later.

I  tried to find a similar example on [Google Books](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22definitely%20easier%20than%22&client=ubuntu&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmiqK-j5TkAhVUyIsBHSh0AqI4ChD8BQgWKAA&biw=1855&bih=984). Unfortunately, since I can't search "definitely" in uppercase, I couldn't find any.

Is this type of omission grammatical or at least common/permissible in colloguial English?

*Context: informal writing/fiction writing*

Comment: See it all the time. Works great in a spy novel. Not so good in a long business letter.

Comment: I can't say that I see it in writing, nor would _I_ use it in writing (except perhaps as a direct quote from a character) - but it's quite common in speech (and I've been known to so use it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colloquially, yes. The second sentence is technically a sentence fragment, because by removing "it was" you remove the subject and verb. However, this is a natural drop in speech. For informal/fiction writing, this is fine. Definitely permissible. :)